# How can we integrate wikihow into mobile apps?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I've integrated mediawiki api into my app, but the response of mediawiki api does not match with wiki how search results. Can anyone share your experience regarding this issue.

Note:
I haven't seen any documentation for wikihow api.

Answer (score 0):

yes .wikihow has a way of hiding their base url(endpoint) so that no api call can derive data from it.the best thing to do is use libraries like scrapy to scrape the website.otherwise.mediawiki apis are not working currently